# Querying the record just once and taking the first record if the column has same value

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am working on a Laravel project. In my project, I am trying to write a query where I only have to select just the first record if a column value is repeating in multiple rows.

Let's imaging I have the following data in the students table.

```
Name: Wai, Age: 22

Name: Yan, Age: 22

Name: Hein, Age: 31
```

As you can see, there are two students with age 22. In that case, I will only have to select the first record to make sure that a student with age 22 appears in the result just once.

How can I query it?

Comment: Are you trying to get all the different ages in your results. So you result set would contain `Wai` AND `Hein`?
Or are you specifying an age and then taking the first result so your set would only be `Wai`?

Comment: Hello, I am trying to get this "specifying an age and then taking the first result so your set would only be Wai".

Comment: Define 'first'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to query all the results, group by age, then order and pick the first from each age group.

```
Student::all()->groupBy('age')->map(function($ageGroup) {
    return $ageGroup()->sortBy('name')->first();
})
->values();
```

Or as a single query you would need to build the equivalent of:

```
SELECT min(`name`), `age` FROM `students`
GROUP BY `age`;
```

That would be something like:

```
Student::select(DB::raw('`age`, min(`name`)'))
    ->groupBy('age')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Hello, I am not just trying to get one record. I am trying to get multiple records.

Comment: If the ages are the same, it will pick the first one.

Comment: Well that's a little more complicated. I'll edit my answer with a new suggestion.

Comment: Is there a way not to query all the result? My database table will be huge and it might have some performance issue.

Comment: You could maybe do it with a subquery. Essentially you'd select the distinct ages and left join the student records. I'm not certain exactly how you'd control the order in that case though.

Comment: That latest edit should just about do the job. That will only ever order by `name` though so you'll have no control over how the first result is picked.